# Python Pandas value from index position

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

This formula used to work for me.  I tried to upgrade my Pandas version.  It seems to work (although I got a boatload a strange message during the pip upgrade).  But now I get a weird result from only this one type of operation.

```
postionVar = str(myDF[(myDF['TableFieldName']==myArray[innerLoop])].index)
```

I used to just get 0 now I get this instead:

```
"Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')"
```

This is literally what goes into my text string where I just need the index position value.  So if 0 is the position of a value I don't get 0 anymore I get this:  `"Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would work:

```
postionVar = str(myDF[myDF['TableFieldName']==myArray[innerLoop]].index[0])
```

This accesses the first element of the index object returned and so can now be cast to the string representation as you desire

Example:

```
In [222]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': arange(5)})
str(df[df['a'] == 3].index[0])
Out[222]:
'3'
```